# centering a text within a button in tk

Tags: python, tkinter

usually buttons in tkinter center their texts automatically but i can't seem to get it i don't know why!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
from getpass import getpass
huh=Tk()
huh.title('Login page')
huh.configure(bg='white')
huh.resizable(False,700)
huh.geometry('925x500+300+200')
my_fr=Frame(huh,width=350,height=350,bg='white')
my_fr.place(x=480,y=90)
btn=Button(my_fr,width=50,border=0,text="Connexion",bg='#000000',fg="#ffffff",font='Railway',anchor=CENTER)
btn.place(x=43,y=300)
huh.mainloop()
```

Comment: The text IS centered in the Button, you're just positioning the Button so it's partially off the side of the window.  I would suggest learning to use the geometry managers that *actually do the work for you* (`.grid()` and `.pack()`), rather than `.place()` that requires you to decide every little detail yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using `grid()` that positions the button, with text centered, at the x, y coordinates used with the original place() statement.

Note that `resizeable()` takes only boolean parameters, so '700' would be interpreted as True. Assuming that a maximum window height of 700 with a minimum height of 500 was the intention, `resizeable()` was replaced with `minsize()` and `maxsize()` statements.

The `geometry()` statement was retained, but if the system's default window position is suitable, then it can be removed.

Replacing `my_fr.grid()` with `my_fr.pack()` would horizontally center the button, thus ignoring the padx specification.

```
import tkinter as tk

huh = tk.Tk()
huh.title('Login page')
huh.configure(bg='white')

huh.geometry('925x500+300+200')
huh.minsize(925, 500)
huh.maxsize(925, 700)

my_fr = tk.Frame(huh, bg='white')
btn = tk.Button(my_fr, width=50, text="Connexion",
                bg='black', fg="white", font='Railway')

my_fr.grid()
btn.grid(padx=43, pady=300)

huh.mainloop()
```